# How to build OpenSSL iOS libs with flips compliance and validate the libraries

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, fips

I'm attempting to build an iOS OpenSSL library with FIPS (Federal Information Processing Standards) compliance enabled. I've modified the build script from the krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL repository (https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL/blob/main/scripts/build.sh) to include FIPS configuration. However, when I integrate the resulting library into my iOS app and attempt to load the FIPS provider, it fails. How can I properly enable FIPS compliance in the OpenSSL library build script for iOS and ensure it's correctly integrated into my app? I've followed these steps in modifying the build script:

## Configure FIPS

${SRC_DIR}/Configure enable-fips
make install_fips
make install

In the build logs, I can see messages indicating the FIPS module is being installed:

```
*** Installing FIPS module
install providers/fips.dylib -> /var/folders/jn/d8ymwfvs4t5942j6y_n930m00000gn/T/tmp.qa2J31kZ81/3.0.8-iPhoneSimulator-x86_64/lib/ossl-modules/fips.dylib
*** Installing FIPS module configuration
install providers/fipsmodule.cnf -> /var/folders/jn/d8ymwfvs4t5942j6y_n930m00000gn/T/tmp.qa2J31kZ81/3.0.8-iPhoneSimulator-x86_64/ssl/fipsmodule.cnf
```

It always fails to load the FIPS provider.
However, when I integrate the resulting library into my iOS app and attempt to load the FIPS provider using the following code:
fips = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(NULL, "fips");
if (fips == NULL) {
printf("Failed to load FIPS provider\n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

How can I properly enable FIPS compliance in the OpenSSL library build script for iOS and ensure it's correctly integrated into my app? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you referring to [FIPS 140](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140)?  FIPS certification is something that you need to pay for. It is a validation of your software and processes.  It isn't a feature that you "turn on"

Comment: Yes, I want to build crypto lib with FIPS compliance using open ssl 3.x version, I'm able to build but not sure about validation of built libraries.

Comment: https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2022/08/24/FIPS-validation-certificate-issued/index.html